# performance: programmatic vs external compilation

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code in a source file, and it takes quite much time to execute. When I compile it programmatically and execute using reflection, it performs ~2 times slower in comparison with a case when I compile it into main assembly along with other code. Programmatic compilation uses option /optimize+, no debug info.
Any ideas what can be the reason?

Comment: Sounds like an excellent case for some profiling...

Answer (score 1):

Place a timer/stopwatch around the actual time consuming code.

I can't see why it would be any slower at all, excluding the reflection part for the loading of it (*I do understand this correctly?*).

Comment: @user536232: Good, but interesting that you see such slowness. How often is reflection used? Once per app, once per loop, etc?

Comment: Once per app, to call an entry method.

Comment: @user536232: If possible, can you provide the code for loading, including any thread creation.

Comment: Does it really matter? I measure performance _inside_ the called code.

Comment: @user536232: I'm at a loss why it should be slower. A simple replication of the issue would help me (or others) understand and see where the problem lies.